# Scaling UIBezierPath makes it move

Tags: core-graphics, scale, cgaffinetransform, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransformscale

I have drawn a `UIBezierPath` inside a `UIView`. With a `pinchGesture` I try to scaled it up and down.

The scaling works, but my problem is that the `UIBezierPath` moves down/upward (if it increases in size it moves downward if the size decreases it moves upward).

How is it possible to set the anchor point for the scaling so the `UIBezierPath` center stays in the same place?

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, 
                                                       recognizer.scale, 
                                                       recognizer.scale);
  [self.selectedObject applyAffineTransform:transform];
  recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

(selectedObject is an object which just applies the `affineTransform` to its `UIBezierPath`)

I tried to apply a translation in addition to the scaling to move it back where it was before, but I don't know how to find the values of the translation so the path stays in the same place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok after many tries I managed to solve it, after the scaling i need to add a translation, for the distance of the translation I needed to compare the bounds of my uibezierpath and substract the change in origine and half the increase in width and height here is the same translated in code:

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGRect originalBounds = self.selectedObject.bounds;

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
[self.selectedObject applyAffineTransform:scale];

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-(self.selectedObject.bounds.origin.x - originalBounds.origin.x) - (self.selectedObject.bounds.size.width - originalBounds.size.width) * 0.5, -(self.selectedObject.bounds.origin.y - originalBounds.origin.y) - (self.selectedObject.bounds.size.height - originalBounds.size.height) * 0.5);
[self.selectedObject applyAffineTransform:translate];

recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

I hope this will help someone else as well.